# Makefile not including libraries

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to compile something and include the pthread library in my makefile, but it doesn't seem to put it on the command line. If i type it directily into the command line it compiles, but if I try to use my makefile it comes up with errors along the lines of undefined refernce to pthread_join and such.

Here is my makefile

```
CC=gcc


all: pthreads 

pthreads: pthreads.c 
    gcc -o pthreads pthreads.c -lpthread
```

Comment: and the line  -- gcc -o pthreads pthreads.c -lpthread -- compiles without a error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `s` on the target line (i.e. you have `pthread:`). So your rule isn't being run. The default (built-in) make rule is (and that rule doesn't have the `-lpthread` bit).

You can either fix your typo or put `-lpthread` in `LDLIBS` and let the built-in rule do the compilation and linking for you.